# How can I add text below a QR code in zxing.net

Tags: c#, zxing.net

So I followed the instructions on the page
https://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/dynamically-generating-qr-codes-in-c.html

and all works 100%

Just wondering if there is a way to save the text of the QRcode below the barcode on the image.

Answer (score 0):

ZXing.Net doesn't write the content below a QR code. You have to do it yourself, f.e. use an image manipulation library or perhaps the builtin Bitmap class of the .Net framework if possible, resize the image to get some free area below the code and write the content to that area.